# Build nodejs wrapper for python library as a package

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

There's some CLI software build in python as a package. I would like to create a NodeJS wrapper around that, so that some users won't need to install python.
So... I would like to have NPM package that can be installed as dev dependency or a global one and it would be a Command Line Interface. It would install some python package and while listening for some specific commands, it would just run some scripts from that package.

Something like:

```
my-tool create-dist directory
```

Would listen to the arguments, but it would pass that argument to python package so that the python piece of software would get the job done.

My question is - is that event possible? To have a package that under the hood runs python commands to external library, without a need to install that python library? I'm new to creating tools like that.

Comment: https://www.pyinstaller.org/ is arguably the most popular Python application bundler. It's probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @AKX Thanks for that!
I built executable python file for Ubuntu. I include that file in my nodejs application. Now I need run it in some kind of "own" environment, so that no matter if you are on windows or ubuntu, the nodejs package will run the ubuntu executable file... Any ideas? :)

Comment: Windows and Linux (Ubuntu) are very different beasts. You'd need to build the executable for both OSes.

Comment: Ok, so what I need to do is build the package for OSes that I'm intrested in, and then inside node package, have basically a bunch of if statements? 
Also, do you know any guide on how to check OS'es so that I can load to the user the correct executable file? Thanks in advance, you already helped me a lot with this, my understanding of the topic is getting bigger

Comment: [`process.platform`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_platform) gets you the current platform. Then yep, an `if` statement would be enough.